# Delete id within nested array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

So far I can only manage to delete the first id (in this case the id with "12345").

Im trying to delete the row with `id` 2 within `books`-array

```
 Libary Table: 

   {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "12345"
    },
    "libaryName": "A random libary",
    "Books": [       
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "1"
            }
            "bookTitle": "Example",
            "TotalPages": "500"                 
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "2"
            }
            "bookTitle": "Delete Me",
            "TotalPages": "400"                 
        }
    ]
}
```

My delete code:

```
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Libary.remove({ _id: req.params.id })
    .then(() => {
      //redirect
    });
});
```

How can I reach and delete the book row where the `id` is 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull-array-of-documents) opertator

```
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Libary.update({ _id: req.params.id }, //This is the Id of library Document
  { $pull: { "Books": {"_id":2) } } }) // This will be the Id of book to be deleted
    .then(() => {
      //redirect
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw, does it matter if I use quotation marks or not? Like at `"Books"`.

Comment: In Javascript it doesn't .  I tested this query on mongo shell and copied it from there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$pull`:

```
Library.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { Books: { _id: 2 } } }
)
```